# how to set a globale variable in google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

when i execute the program i receive variable (Fx_row: lign 6) undefined, i declare it in ligne 23, can u help me to resolve it , sorry for my english.

```
if (contents.callback_query) {

 var id_callback = contents.callback_query.from.id;
 var data = contents.callback_query.data;

if (data == 'Congés') {

  var Congés = expenseSheet.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
  sendText(Fx_row);

}

}

 else if (contents.message) {
var id_message = contents.message.from.id;
var text = contents.message.text;
var firstName = contents.message.from.first_name;
var TextUpperCase = text.toUpperCase();

for (var i = 0; i <password.length ; i++) {

 if (TextUpperCase == password[i][0]){

var Tosearch = TextUpperCase;
var TextFinder = expenseSheet.createTextFinder(Tosearch).findAll();
for (i = 0; i < TextFinder.length; i++) {
var F_row = TextFinder[i].getRow();
var Fx_row = F_row.toFixed(0);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `when i execute the program i receive variable (Fx_row: lign 6) undefined, i declare it in ligne 23,`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: It's not clear to me what your doing but take a look at [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code

> sendText(Fx_row)

is used, but Fx_row isn't declared as a variable until this line

> var Fx_row = F_row.toFixed(0);

So it's throwing an error that the variable hasn't been declared yet.   Should it really be Fx_row though?  Because based on the line right before it, it looks like the variable to send would be Conges & not Fx_row-

```
var Congés = expenseSheet.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
sendText(Congés);   // instead of sendText(Fx_row);
```

Answer (score -1):

we update the code like that, but still not working, when i execute the code i get message "undefined"

```
    if (contents.callback_query) {

 var id_callback = contents.callback_query.from.id;
 var data = contents.callback_query.data;

if (data == 'Congés') {
  var Fx_row = F_row.toFixed(0);
  var Congés = expenseSheet.getRange(Fx_row, 5).getValue();
  sendText(Congés);
  Logger.log(Congés);

}

}

 else if (contents.message) {
var id_message = contents.message.from.id;
var text = contents.message.text;
var firstName = contents.message.from.first_name;
var TextUpperCase = text.toUpperCase();

for (var i = 0; i <password.length ; i++) {

 if (TextUpperCase == password[i][0]){

var Tosearch = TextUpperCase;
var TextFinder = expenseSheet.createTextFinder(Tosearch).findAll();
for (i = 0; i < TextFinder.length; i++) {
var F_row = TextFinder[i].getRow();
var Fx_row = F_row.toFixed(0);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your answer is not adding any value. Please be precise in your responses to help others devs.